# Why cant i see file_get_contents request in firefox and chrome dev tools under network activity?

Tags: php, http, developer-tools, web-developer-toolbar

I have 2 files. index.php and form.php

index.php

```
<?php
echo "123"
?>
```

form.php

```
<?php
$result = file_get_contents('http://localhost/fatsecret/index.php');
var_dump($result);
?>
```

i can see result "123" in form.php. But when i go to dev-tools - network i cant see any request to index.php. Why? this doesnt show in firefox and chrome dev tools.

Comment: The browser is not doing the request, the server is. The server also accesses the file directly so the browser does not know there is a request in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply because the request to `http://localhost/fatsecret/index.php` is not coming from your browser.

The request is going directly from your PHP code - which is running on your *server* - to the `localhost` server (in this case I assume it's actually the same server, but that's not relevant) which hosts the `index.php` file. The network path for that request is from one server to another. The browser is not involved in that.

The flow goes like this:

```
browser -> form.php -> index.php
```

The browser can only see the first step (`browser -> form.php`). It does not know what `form.php` is doing in the background while it's being executed. It simply waits for `form.php` to return some data. It does not know (or care) how `form.php` got hold of that data.

---

In summary:

The browser only sends a request to `form.php`. The request to `index.php` does not come from the browser, therefore the browser cannot log or monitor it.

Comment: thank you. it's clear this case